# How to resize images with Django when uploading to AWS S3?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, boto3

I am uploading and storing my media files on DigitalOcean Spaces (which is built on AWS) with Django using the Boto 3 package. Everything works fine and I am able to view my images on my site, however, I get an error when trying to modify the image using Pillow on upload. I would like to convert the images to JPEG and resize and optimize them.

This is how my model's current save function looks:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.image:
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.mode != 'RGB':
            img = img.convert('RGB')
        if img.width > 100:
            ratio = img.width / img.height
            height = 100 / ratio
            output_size = (100, height)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
        img.save(self.image.path, optimize=True, quality=90, format='JPEG')
```

If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi have you found a solution to this problem ?